# Como se pone por defecto la clase main en c# con visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

Quiero que cuando entre al programa, la clase main se ponga por defecto, en donde le tengo que poner para poner esa configuracion?

Comment: Si inicias un proyecto de consola, la clase main esta ya escrita por defecto... como iniciaste tu proyecto?

Comment: Teniendo el link para leer la documentación para las instrucciones de nivel superior https://aka.ms/new-console-template , Alex vino a preguntar a StackOverflow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En `.net 6` ya no es necesario declarar la clase `Program` en el archivo `Program.cs`, ya que se utilizan [instrucciones de nivel superior](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) donde está implícito que todo lo que escribas en "Program.cs" quedará dentro de la clase y dentro del método `Main` (tu punto de entrada a la aplicación).

De hecho, ya todas las plantillas de la nueva versión vienen con la clase `Program` y el método `Main` implícito y aunque es totalmente opcional usarlo o no, conviene acostumbrarse y respetar esta nueva sintaxis que ha establecido `Microsoft` por defecto.

De cualquier manera, hay total compatibilidad con las versiones anteriores, por lo que puedes simplemente remplazar esas líneas y tu programa funcionará:

```
using System;

namespace MyApp // El namespace depende del nombre que le diste al proyecto al iniciarlo.
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Otra opción sería inicializar la plantilla en visual studio con `.net 5`  y no con `.net 6`.

Puedes seguir este [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0) de la documentación de microsoft para más detalles y leer sobre las nuevas características del lenguaje [acá](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements). También incluso en la plantilla que te te da visual studio tienes el [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) donde se explican los cambios. Hay muchas novedades en la sintaxis, como los using globales, cambios en las declaraciones del namespaces, entre otros.